# 'not fool enough to dance on the old strings', is it an idiom? This phrase is from 'The Invisible Man' by H.G Wells

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs, literature

In the book of 'The Invisible Man' by Wells, there is this sentence; "Kemp, you're not **fool enough to dance on the old strings**. Can't you see my position?"

In this particular scene, Griffin(the invisible man) was telling Dr.Kemp(they went to the same university) a story about how he became invisible and what happened since. When Kemp heard about Griffin's invasion and attack a man, he said something negative and Griffin got angry and said that sentence. It sounds like something that he thought Kemp would not be that much old-fashioned. Is it right?

While Griffin was telling, he described how he tied a man in a sheet to keep a man from attacking him, Griffin said "It was rather a good idea to keep the idiot scared and quiet, and a devilish hard thing to get out of—***head away from the string***." Here is another string. Are those tow words of 'string' related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that TIM is irritated that Kemp can't see that invisibility has changed the old rules of behavior and thus is tied to them like a [marionette](https://www.google.com/search?q=marionette&espv=2&biw=1463&bih=744&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIvtndv4PaxgIVTimICh2-7Qkf#imgrc=957clWAyPsl08M%3A)

In the second instance, TIM means that he has tied a man in a sheet, closing the loose ends of the sheet with string in such a way that the unfortunate man's head is at the opposite end of shroud and his feet are near the knots.  In that position, it would be hard ("devilish hard") for the man to escape.

The two uses of string are not related.  The first is figurative; the second, literal.